# Docker swarm deployment takes time and causes container to kill the service

Tags: docker, spring-boot, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I've been experimenting with docker. As part of it, I've been using a simple spring-boot application,

https://github.com/siva54/simpleusercontrol

When I run the application within a simple docker container, I see that the application logs show the below line,

> 2017-07-03 02:27:25.388  INFO 5 --- [ost-startStop-1]
>   o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext:
>   initialization completed in 4963 ms

However when I run the same thing with docker swarm, The application takes up longer time,

> 2017-07-03 00:32:56.483  INFO 5 --- [ost-startStop-1]
>   o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext:
>   initialization completed in 48699 ms

Also the application doesn't start up, Instead in the logs (docker logs <>), I do see see a string value "Killed". I'm guessing it might be due the to massive time, Possibly a timeout setting on the docker might be killing the service.

Can anyone please help me setting the timeout or fixing the application so as to not take that huge amount of time.

Please find the below links for more info,

Docker version : Docker version 17.06.0-ce, build 02c1d87

Dockerfile (https://github.com/siva54/simpleusercontrol/blob/master/Dockerfile)

Docker Compose (https://github.com/siva54/simpleusercontrol/blob/master/docker-compose.yml)

If anyone wants to experiment with my application, You can pull that image using "siva54/simpleusercontrol".

If you can startup the application and find the link (localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html#/) working for you, That should be working.

The following were used to run the swarm,

Initialize swarm

> docker swarm init

Run the application

> docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml app1

The following were used to run without swarm,

> docker run siva54/simpleusercontrol

All this was done on images created using vagrant.

Comment: It will be helpful to know some more information: Docker versions, Docker commands used to run the containers in both swarm and non-swarm, the actual full output of `docker logs` in both cases, and also the location of the swarm and non-swarm hosts (if they are on different hardware).

Comment: I'm using "Docker version 17.06.0-ce, build 02c1d87" and as for the commands, I've used the ones shared in the docker tutorials (https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part3/#scale-the-app). I've updated the same in my question above too for reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things that jump out at me here.

1. The `Killed` message in logs is usually something that the Linux Kernel OOM killer generates. I would  check the output of `dmesg` on the host and probably also `docker ps -a`, `docker service ls`, and `docker stack ls` to see if they show any scheduling or exit code errors. This could be an indicator that the host doesn't have enough memory (for example, if the host has only 512 MB of memory, the application + host OS may be over the limit).
2. The `docker-compose.yml` you link to defines a memory limit of 128 MB. But when I run start a regular container from that image it is using about 345 MB just idling. I am guessing that the 128 MB limit is causing the JVM garbage collector to work overtime, causing slow startup times for the application. It is also probably responsible for the OOM killer killing off the application. I'd try bumping up the memory limit to maybe 512 MB.

Comment: [ 7763.720387] Task in /docker/000cdf122674c15d8fc1f640af3a94290650a7798e63fc5626c709dff301833b killed as a result of limit of /docker/000cdf122674c15d8fc1f640af3a94290650a7798e63fc5626c709dff301833b
[ 7763.720388] memory: usage 131072kB, limit 131072kB, failcnt 1615

Comment: I do see this in the dmesg log. Does this tell anything?

Comment: I did try updating the memory on the docker-compose.yml to memory: 512M. But still the same issue. Tomcat is starting up real slow and killing the container task.

Comment: How much memory is on the host? Also, where are the hosts? You didn't answer this from my original comment.

Comment: I'm using a local vm. I've just now verified that my VM has a low memory of 512M.

Comment: vagrant@workstation:/vagrant_data/simpleusercontrol$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           489        341        148          0          3         92
-/+ buffers/cache:        245        244
Swap:            0          0          0

Comment: Looks like you have identified the issue then :)  See the last sentence in my first suggestion. If it wasn't clear, you need to give the host more than 512 MB of memory (the application is requiring 345 MB which is only giving 144 MB left for the OS and other applications. Likely not enough.

Comment: Agreed. All this time, I was trying to increase the container memory size but not the host. Also one more problem I'm facing is the application is taking long time to load on to a swarm.

Comment: 2017-07-03 04:18:54.486  INFO 5 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-07-03 04:18:54.487  INFO 5 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 61196 ms

Comment: This is like 14-15 times of that of a non-swarm.

Comment: You mean, it is still slow after upgrading the memory?

Comment: Yep. Its still the same loading time.

Comment: I did see that the time decreased to 10s when I bumped up the cpus from 0.1 to 0.5 though.

Comment: Just for the record, it's a Java application, so it will always try to consume as much memory as it gets (as it won't perform garbage collection since it doesn't know it's reaching the limits). I don't know the defaults within the container, but if you set `-Xms` and `-Xmx` to proper values below the container limit, it should do a lot better. The example you've provided by the OP already allows you to easily configure these parameters through setting the `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable.